# Finding corresponding rectangle coordinates given grid points

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, opencv

I have processed an image using openCV to obtain the image pattern. The image pattern is represented by 2 *Python* lists of horizontal and vertical lines respectively. The lines represent the borders of the patterns.

`fx = horizontal lines`
`fy = vertical lines`

Each list is arranged in order based on the distance from the top left corner of the image. Next, I use the following to calculate the intersection points of those discovered lines:

```py
def get_corners(fx,fy):
    corners = []
    for x_line in fx:
        for y_line in fy:
            corner = get_intersection(x_line,y_line)
            if corner is not None:
                corners.append(corner)
```

This should give me the `corners` (formatted: `(x,y)`) in order from left to right, top to bottom. Now I want to use those coordinates to crop rectangles out of the image.

The size of the `corners` list varies and the patterns stack, meaning they have points in common. Given the list of points, the and the size of the lists of lines `fx` and `fy`:

**How do I use the points to crop the rectangles?**

Feel free to change `get_corners()` if you need.

Here's an example: The pattern detection yields 4 possible rectangles in a 2x2. This means list `points` has a total of 9 values in it.

```
Points: [[],[],[],
         [],[],[],
         [],[],[]]
```

I am able to crop the first rectangle using something like this:

```py
x1,y1 = points[0] #top left corner of the first pattern
x2,y2 = points[5] #bottom right corner of the first pattern
#rectangle
rectange = img[y1:y2,x1:x2]
```

Comment: Do you have an real output example and the expected one? In order to see what's wrong in it, cause I'm not completely sure to have understood your issue. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an example because I can't finish the algorithm by myself. I updated my question to show what I have so far, but I used hard values for the points. I need to be able to choose those values based on how many points I get, which is based on the amount of lines I get.

Comment: Why would you even bother with the corner points? The lines are much easier to handle (just extract the rectangles in the same way as you extract the corners). How can two orthogonal lines not intersect? Are they line *segments*?

Comment: The lines go all the way across the image. They are represented as `(rho, theta)` That means one horizontal line can represent multiple rectangles. The only way I know where they start or end is by using the intersections. Can you explain how you would use the lines?

Comment: That links explains cropping. This question requests a method for using an array of points, to do the cropping. I'll work on getting an output.

Comment: Not very sure what you are asking.  Possible to use paint to draw the input and desired output and update it here?

Comment: At least add an input image sample with highlighted the rectangles you need

Comment: In your single example, should `x2,y2 = points[5]` really to be `x2,y2 = points[4]` in order to match your description of 4 rectangles in a 2x2?

Comment: And is your `img` a numpy array?

Answer (score 5):

Stabbing in the dark here, but is this your intermediate image? I'm also assuming you're differentiating between squares and rectangles, that is, you don't want squares, only rectangles.

[image]

If this is the case, I'd use the following steps:

```
cnt_rectangles = 0
rectangle_list = []
for index in np.arange(len(points)-1):
   p = points[index]
   q = points[index+1]
   if (p[0] == q[0]) || p[1] == q[1]
       #the rectangle vertices must not have the same column or row. reject.
       continue
   else if abs(p[0] - q[0]) == abs(p[1] - q[1]):
       #this is a square. reject
       continue
   else:
       #this is a rectangle
       cnt_rectangels+=1
       rectangle_list.append((p, q))
```

Comment: Yes this is the idea. But won't this only compare adjacent points? also if the matrix is a 3x3 then you will having overlapping rectangles.

Comment: @JoshSharkey this will compare every point with every other point so that you have every combination. You shouldn't get overlapping rectangles. Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but here's a solution that assumes your `img` variable is a numpy array (since the question is tagged with `opencv`) with intersection point indices in `corners`. Note that I modified the `get_corners()` function to build the corners in rows instead of a single flat array for easier processing, as you indicated this was ok.

```
import numpy as np

def get_corners(fx, fy):
    corners = []
    for x_line in fx:
        row = [] # NOTE: we're building rows here!
        for y_line in fy:
            corner = get_intersection(x_line, y_line)
            if corner is not None:
                row.append(corner)
        corners.append(row)

def get_crops(img, corners):
    crops = []
    for i, row in enumerate(corners[0:-1]):
        for j in range(len(row) - 1):
            x1, y1 = row[j]
            next_row = corners[i+1]
            x2, y2 = next_row[j+1]
            # this slicing works with my test_img,
            # but you may need to adjust it for yours
            crops.append(img[x1:x2+1, y1:y2+1])
    return crops

test_corners = [
    [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2] ],
    [ [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2] ],
    [ [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2] ],
]

test_img = np.array(corners) # test img to easily see indices

crops = get_crops(test_img, test_corners)

for i, crop in enumerate(crops):
    print("crop [{}]: {}\n".format(i, crop))
```

Here's the output of the test run. Of course, a real image would have other data, but this shows how to do the slicing for my `test_img` numpy array.

```
crop [0]: [[[0 0] [0 1]]
           [[1 0] [1 1]]]

crop [1]: [[[0 1] [0 2]]
           [[1 1] [1 2]]]

crop [2]: [[[1 0] [1 1]]
           [[2 0] [2 1]]]

crop [3]: [[[1 1] [1 2]]
           [[2 1] [2 2]]]
```